# reshape a dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .csv file like this

```
ID FirstName LastName  Age   FirstName   LastName   Age
1   Sid       Than      21     Sidd         Thang   26
2   Art       Mari      21     Arth         Mariap  28
```

When I read this inside python using pandas the column names automatically changes to FirstName_y LastName_y Age_y for all the second occurances.

Now, I want to change the df to look like this,

```
Name_Key        ID   FirstName LastName   Age
1_Sid_Than      1     Sid       Than       21
1_Sidd_Thang    1     Sidd      Thang      26
2_Art_Mari      2     Art       Mari       21
2_Arth_Mariap   2     Arth      Mariap     28
```

ID is a string in my case. 
How Can I do this using Pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract values in two different dataframes and then concatenate them

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
df_1 = df[['ID', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'Age']]
df_2 = df[['ID', 'FirstName_y', 'LastName_y', 'Age_y']]
df_2.columns = ['ID', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'Age']
df = pd.concat([df_1, df_2], axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

`wide_to_long` will work for repeat multiple times

```
pd.wide_to_long(df,['FirstName', 'LastName' ,'Age'],i='ID0',j='drop',sep='_',suffix='\w')
Out[390]: 
         FirstName LastName  Age
ID0 drop                        
1   x          Sid     Than   21
2   x          Art     Mari   21
1   y         Sidd    Thang   26
2   y         Arth   Mariap   28
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a lambda function to concatenate the items of the 3 columns.

I create a data Frame:

```
    df=pd.DataFrame([['Ann', 'Black',5], ['Peter','Black', 5], ['Laura','White', 8],
                    ['Sean','Green',9]], index=[1,1,2,3], 
                    columns=['Name', 'Family_name', 'Age'])
```

Data Frame:

```
        Name Family_name  Age
    1    Ann       Black    5
    1  Peter       Black    5
    2  Laura       White    8
    3   Sean       Green    9
```

I  generate a new column, `ID`, with the indexes and transform the new columns' items from int to str because later I will concatenate this with string, so all the 3 columns have to be str.

```
    df['col']=df.index.astype(str)
```

Data frame now:

```
        Name Family_name  Age  ID
    1    Ann       Black    5   1
    1  Peter       Black    5   1
    2  Laura       White    8   2
    3   Sean       Green    9   3
```

I apply a **lambda** function:

```
    col2=df['Family_name']
    col1=df['Name']
    col3=df['ID']
    new=map(lambda row0,row1,row2:row0+'_'+row1+'_'+row2,col3,col1,col2)
    new_list=list(new)
    df['new']=new_list
```

And you get:

```
        Name Family_name  Age  ID            new
    1    Ann       Black    5   1    1_Ann_Black
    1  Peter       Black    5   1  1_Peter_Black
    2  Laura       White    8   2  2_Laura_White
    3   Sean       Green    9   3   3_Sean_Green
```

You can then re-order columns as you wish